# How do I use the search term +?

Tags: google-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Forced words in Google search query are being ignored, plus no longer working as explicit inclusion](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19465/forced-words-in-google-search-query-are-being-ignored-plus-no-longer-working-as)

When I have multiple search terms, I like to use the '+' to tell Google Search that the word MUST be in the search results. For example 'blueberry cheesecake pie' will return many results, but not necessarily having all three search terms in each result.

When I try to use the '+', Google tells me that it took the operator out, and if I want to search for a phrase, I need to use quotation marks.

How do I tell Google to search for `+blueberry +cheesecake +pie` now?

Comment: In your example you would use "blueberry" "cheesecake" "pie" now.